# Torch/Lua element wise multiplication of 2D and 1D tensors

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch

I'm trying to preform element wise multiplication between 2D batch tensor(128x512) and 1D tensor(512).

Currently, I'm doing it in this why:

```
   nbatch = input:size(1)
   for i = 1 , nbatch , 1 do
      self.output[i]:cmul(self.noise)
   end
```

It works and I get expected results, but I think it is not the best efficient why to do it.

Can it be done more efficiently?

How can I extend it for nD tensors element wise multiplied with (n-1)D tensors ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
self.output:cmul(self.noise:view(1, self.output:size(2)):expandAs(self.output))
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to extend it for more dimensions

Comment: You can expand multiple singleton dimensions, e.g. `torch.rand(3):view(1, 3, 1):expand(2, 3, 5)`.